# Filter in google maps not working (JS)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have JS script file where I get markers from back-end and initialize map

Here is code:

```
    function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
        {
            zoom: 5,
            center: { lat: 51.0742853, lng: 11.0294547 },
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });
    var centerControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var centerControlDiv2 = document.createElement('div');
    var centerControl = new CenterControl(centerControlDiv, map);
    var centerControl2 = new CenterControl1(centerControlDiv, map);

    centerControlDiv.index = 1;
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(centerControlDiv);
    getDriving();
} //map initialization
// get Driving and show on layer
function getDriving() {
    var url = $('#map').data('request-url2');
    $.getJSON(url,
        function (data) {


            $.each(data,
                function (i, item) {
                    marker.push({
                        'location': new google.maps.LatLng(item.Latitude, item.Longitude),
                        'map': map,
                        'weight': item.Speed,
                        'radius': 10,
                        'date': item.CurrentDateTime
                    });
                });
            var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(marker);

            heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
                data: pointArray
            });
            heatmap.setMap(map);
        });
};
```

I need to filter them by date

So I wrote this function

```
 $('#filter').on('click',
   function () {
       var startValue = $('#startDate').val(moment($(this).val()).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
       var endValue = $('#endDate').val(moment($(this).val()).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
       map.markers = [];
       map.markers.push(marker);
       console.log(map.markers);
       $.each(map.markers, function (i, marker) {
           if (marker.date === startValue)
               marker.setVisible(false);
           else
               marker.setVisible(true);
       });
   });
```

In console I see all my markers

Here is screenshot
[image: Screen]

But I have this error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: marker.setVisible is not a function

How I can solve it?

Comment: What do you get if you add console.log(marker) inside $.each? Also find out where you are appearing in that if else statement.

Comment: @Neil will look now

Comment: I get 37 objects, as at screen in question@Neil

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/3X5t9 here is screeen @Neil

Comment: What do you mean about `if else`. I have condition @Neil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use setMap()  and not setVisible()

```
if (marker.date === startValue)
           marker.setMap(null);
       else
           marker.setMap(map);
```

obvious the map object must be accessibile by the on click function

Comment: marker.setMap(null) hide the marker,   marker.setMap(map) show the marker

Comment: okay. I understood. 

anyway I have this error.

But if I delete else all okay and I don't have errors.


But I have another trouble.

If I write this condition `if (marker.date === startValue)
                   marker.setMap(null);`
It not hide markers.

Comment: Maybe it related to that date on screen is different of date in input?

Comment: You have asked for a question and i have answer  to this question ..  S:O. is not a coding service  .. so if my answer for your first question  the mar my answer  as accepted  ..  and for other question post a new properly described questio ...  eventually comment me the link to the new question